# Convert address to string in LIGO

Tags: address, ligo, string, types

How do I convert an `address` type to a `string` type in LIGO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot convert an `address` to a `string` in Michelson. You could cheat by going through pack and inspecting the binary representation but it is unlikely something you would want to do.

Comment: OK. I solved my problem another way, by changing the JS signature generation. I still am curious about the answer, though. How would you achieve this? We can probably learn something from getting this explanation.

Comment: Cheating involves going through pack and inspecting the binary representation. Very ugly.

Comment: Voted up. Will gladly accept answer if you show the specific code to do this. Either in an actual programming language or as pseudo code.

Comment: You first compute `pack(my_address)` then you can do a for loop on each byte of the meaningful part (not the prefix) with `slice` and associate a string by using a pre-determined dictionary. If you want to write the exact address, you need to implement the base 58 translation in Michelson. It’s obviously super cumbersome to do. You possibly also need to take entry points in addresses into account but I guess that, at this point, you should really have stopped caring.

Comment: i need to do this inside a unit test is there an explicit example to get the string of a contract.address