# Concat Address to String in smartpy

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, string

My use case is, I need to concat address with string this way,
"ab" + sp.self_address + "cd" .
How to achieve this in smartpy ?

Comment: Apologies for the duplicate, I thought it was easy to convert an address to bytes, and there was a sample in that link of concatenating bytes to a string. Seems i'm mistaken as there are unanswered questions around this topic. I've reopened the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot concatenate `address` to `string` without converting `address` to `string` and for that see https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/2894/5292

Can you explain in detail your use case ?

Most of the time, when people ask this question, there is a better way to design their smart contract and client interfaces.

The conversion should be done on the client side or not at all. In the second case, you may use a `sp.record` as a replacement (for example for an error message).

Notice that this question is different from.

> How to create a `lambda f` such as `f(a) = s` where `a` is an address and `s` the unique `string` computed from `a`.